# Python: display first element of tuple in cursor

Tags: python, loops, cursor, tuples

I have the following code:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(database='test', user='me', password='pwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = ( "select id from T where project = 10" )
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

result is showing as:

```
[(Decimal('476749'),), (Decimal('478045'),), (Decimal('479713'),)]
```

is it possible to show it as : `[476749, 478045, 479713]`

Comment: `result = [int(x[0]) for x in cursor.fetchall()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use zip/map when python is so much more elegant?

```
[int(i[0]) for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` function to get the first items and `map` to convert the decimals to integer:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> map(int,zip(*[(decimal.Decimal('476749'),), (decimal.Decimal('478045'),), (decimal.Decimal('479713'),)])[0])
[476749, 478045, 479713]
```

And in your code :

```
result = map(int,zip(*cursor.fetchall()))
```